# How to separate different "gravitational fields" in D3?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a force enabled SVG visualisation where I want smaller circles to be attracted to bigger circles. This attraction works by calculating the elements' centre point and change it in iterations for every "tick" in the visualisation, to keep the items from going over the centre of the nodes I use a function to change the charge of the items depending on their size.

I used Mike's code here as a basis: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/#14

My problem comes here - it seems like the bigger circles are affecting each others "gravitational fields" - is there a way I can separate them from eachother?

[image]

Force layout setup:

```
var w = 1280,
    h = 800,
    color = d3.scale.category10();

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.0)
    .charge(function(d){
      return -10 * d.r;
    })
    .size([w, h]);
```

Element drawing:

```
var g = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    ;


  g.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 40)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 0 + ","+ 0 + ")"; })
    .style("fill", fill)
    .call(force.drag);

  g.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".31em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.label;
    });
```

Animation loop:

```
force.on("tick", function(e) {
    var k = e.alpha * 0.5;

    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      var center = nodes[node.type];

      dx = center.x - node.x;
      dy = center.y - node.y;
      node.x += dx * k;
      node.y += dy * k;

    });

    svg.selectAll(".circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  });
```

Adding smaller circles:

```
svg.on("mousemove", function() {
    var p1 = d3.svg.mouse(this),
      node = {
        type: Math.random() * 3 | 0,
        x: p1[0],
        y: p1[1],
        r: 1.5,
        px: (p0 || (p0 = p1))[0],
        py: p0[1]
      };

    p0 = p1;

    svg.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .data([node])
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", fill);

    nodes.push(node);
    force.start();
  });
```

Comment: You can use different force layouts.

Comment: Actually,the gravity is applied globally to all nodes and is a function of the distance of the node from the centre of the layout, there is no interaction _between_ nodes due to gravity. In your case you roll your own gravity based on node.type and you need to switch off the global gravity with `force.gravity(0)`